# select the highest record between two table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two table. One table contains graduation records and the second table contains post graduation records. A candidate must have graduation, but it is not necessarily to have post graduation.

My question is to select the post graduation record if the candidate has post graduation else only graduation.

table 1 graduation_table

```
rollno | degree | division
--------------------------
001    | B.tech | 1st
002    | B.sc   | 1st
003    | BA     | 1st
```

table 2 postgraduation_table

```
rollno | degree | division
--------------------------
002    | M.sc   | 1st
```

the result must be

```
rollno | degree | division
--------------------------
001    | B.tech | 1st
002    | M.sc   | 1st
003    | BA     | 1st
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want all rows from `graduation_table` which do not have a row in `postgraduation_table` plus those in `postgraduation_table`. This can be expressed with a `not exists` and `union` query:

```
select gt.rollno, gt.degree, gt.division
from graduation_table gt
where not exists (select * 
                  from postgraduation_table pg
                  where pg.rollno = gt.rollno)

union all

select rollno, degree, division
from postgraduation_table
order by rollno;
```

Online example: http://rextester.com/IFCQR67320

Answer (score 1):

```
select
    rollno,
    case when p.degree is null then g.degree else p.degree end as degree,
    case when p.division is null then g.division else p.division end as division
from
    grad g
    left join
    post p using (rollno)
```

Or better as suggested in the comments:

```
select
    rollno,
    coalesce (p.degree, g.degree) as degree,
    coalesce (p.division, g.division) as division
from
    grad g
    left join
    post p using (rollno)
```

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-conditional.html#functions-coalesce-nvl-ifnull

Answer (score 0):

Take a union of both tables, and introduce a position column, to rank the relative importance of the two tables.  The postgraduate table has a `pos` value of 1, and the graduate table has a value of 2.  Then, apply `ROW_NUMBER()` over this union query and assign a row number to each `rollno` group of records (presumed to be either one or at most two records).  Finally, perform one more outer subquery to retain the most important record, postgraduate first, graduate second.

```
SELECT rollno, degree, division
FROM
(
    SELECT
        rollno, degree, division,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY rollno ORDER BY pos) rn
    FROM
    (
        SELECT p.*, 1 AS pos p FROM postgraduation_table
        UNION ALL
        SELECT p.*, 2 FROM graduation_table p
    ) t
) t
WHERE t.rn = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

This should make your needs :

```
SELECT dg.rollno, CASE WHEN pg IS NOT NULL THEN pg.degree ELSE gd.degree END AS degree, dg.division
  FROM graduation_table AS dg
  LEFT OUTER JOIN postgraduation_table AS pg USING (rollno)
 GROUP BY dg.rollno, dg.division;
```

Hope this help.